# Delete operation in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am having to hard code a binary search tree for a class. I somewhat understand the delete method for removing a node but I am getting mixed information as to what I replace it with...

I have been told to use the left-most node in the right subtree OR the rightmost node in the left subtree... Do I replace with the smallest node in right subtree or largest Node in left subtree?

Does it make a difference which one that I use? Should I implement both and have the program alternatively switch off from each one?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which one you implement. Replacing the deleted node with the rightmost node of the left subtree or the leftmost node of the right subtree will both result in a valid binary search tree.

If you want, you could alternate between them to try and maintain some balance. You could also choose the subtree with the higher height to remove from as well to achieve a similar thing.